# dynamic recursive xslt to update an XML from another XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

**Background/Summary:**
i have a very large nested (Job-XML) XML. We are doing a process that allows users to make changes to data ( a visual of the XML),  we then need to map those changes back to the XML so we can push the update in XML back to the source system. User could change 1 thing or 1 million things, at any level of the document they see.

The Platform we are using that allows users to make changes produces a list of tags and their values (Changes List), that the user changed. we mapped those tags to the source XML location but doing this in a java transformer will be bulky and not fun to maintain.

ideally i want to generate a XML from the 3rd party platform XML (Change XML) that has locations in the original XML to update and identifiers to say which part of the original XML (Jobs XML) should be changed.

**Problem**:
Given Changes.xml with modifications, for each of the mod, fields - replace that field in the Jobs.xml with the value for that mod IF that element matches the identifier conditions called out in the modification.

Ive already figured that i can dynamically select Xpaths given a list of Xpaths and update that value dynamically as well. Which works IF there were no conditions on selection, but there are.

i can use XSL 1-3 doesnt matter.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--CHANGES.XML -->
<accounts>
<changes>
        <modifications>
            <modification>
                <parentpath>accounts/locationArea/thisloc</parentpath>

                <mods>
                    <mod>
                        <path>/accounts/locationArea/thisloc/jobs/job</path>
                        <field>salary</field>
                        <val>1000</val>
                    </mod>

                </mods>
                <identifiers>
                    <identifier>
                        <path>accounts/locationArea/thisloc</path>
                        <field>key</field>
                        <val>1</val>
                    </identifier>
                    <identifier>
                        <path>accounts/locationArea/thisloc/jobs/job</path>
                        <field>building</field>
                        <val>1</val>
                    </identifier>
                    <identifier>
                        <path>accounts/locationArea/thisloc/jobs/job</path>
                        <field>role</field>
                        <val>Kitchen</val>
                    </identifier>
                </identifiers>
            </modification>
            <modification>
                <parentpath>accounts/locationArea/thisloc</parentpath>

                <mods>
                    <mod>
                        <path>/accounts/locationArea/thisloc</path>
                        <field>manager</field>
                        <val>Sam</val>
                    </mod>
<mod>
                        <path>/accounts/locationArea/thisloc</path>
                        <field>updated</field>
                        <val>true</val>
                    </mod>
                </mods>
                <identifiers/>
            </modification>
        </modifications>
    </changes>
</accounts>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Jobs.XML, this is the one we need to edit -->
<accounts>
<locationArea>
        <thisloc>
            <title>locaton1</title>
            <manager>Dean</manager>
            <key>1</key>
            <jobs>
                <job>
                    <tag>1</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>BA</role>
                    <salary>100</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>2</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>IT</role>
                    <salary>200</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>3</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>Kitchen</role>
                    <salary>300</salary>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </thisloc>
        <thisloc>
            <title>locaton2</title>
            <manager>Smith</manager>
                        <updated>false</updated>
            <key>2</key>
            <jobs>
                <job>
                    <tag>1</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>Kitchen</role>
                    <salary>300</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>2</tag>
                    <building>2</building>
                    <role>Mail</role>
                    <salary>400</salary>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </thisloc>
    </locationArea>
</accounts>
```

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="http://myns">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:param name="changesXML" select="doc('changes.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="changes" select="$changesXML/accounts/changes/modifications/modification/mods/mod"/>

   <xsl:template name="dynomatch" match="*[$changes/path]/*[local-name()=$changes/field]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$changes/val"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**i want the results to look like this:**

- (1) the 'salary' for the kitchen role for ONLY location key 1 was updated from 300 too 1000
- (2) the 'manager' for all locations was changed to "Sam"
- and (3) 'updated' was set to true for all locations, and added for those who were missing the tag all together.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<accounts>
<locationArea>
        <thisloc>
            <title>locaton1</title>
            <manager>Sam</manager>
                        <updated>true</updated>
            <key>1</key>
            <jobs>
                <job>
                    <tag>1</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>BA</role>
                    <salary>100</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>2</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>IT</role>
                    <salary>200</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>3</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>Kitchen</role>
                    <salary>350</salary>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </thisloc>
        <thisloc>
            <title>locaton2</title>
            <manager>Sam</manager>
                        <updated>true</updated>
            <key>2</key>
            <jobs>
                <job>
                    <tag>1</tag>
                    <building>1</building>
                    <role>Kitchen</role>
                    <salary>300</salary>
                </job>
                <job>
                    <tag>2</tag>
                    <building>2</building>
                    <role>Mail</role>
                    <salary>400</salary>
                </job>
            </jobs>
        </thisloc>
    </locationArea>
</accounts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, and as someone who believes that XSLT is very versatile, this looks like a job for a procedural language. With XSLT, you filter, so on every single node from the input document (jobs.xml), you have to look through the modification list and decide whether the current node fits all the criteria of any of the modification nodes. If nothing else, it will be pretty slow.

What XSLT cannot do is doing in-place updates. It always produces a new output from an input, although it can be used to simply copy part of the nodes from the input into the output. However, it seems much more "natural" to open the source document, and then iterate the modification list, searching one or more nodes fitting the criteria list, manipulating the values and adding/updating the "updated" attribute.

There is also a fair bit of intelligence required to interpret the criteria list. For example, /changes/modifications/modification[1]/identifiers/identifier[1] and identifier[2] have different paths, so one qualifies the parent element, while the other references the element to be modified. This all has to be coded into some logic that actually compares paths and does the matching, and doing that with XSLT will be very painful.